# Burninate the "physics" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

What's the purpose of the [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) tag? Every question is supposed to be about physics.

I've tried removing some myself but new users keep using it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181772/

Comment: Since the astronomy site was migrated in, it's technically possible to have non-physics related questions pertaining to astronomy. And I suppose a physics question related to it also... not saying the tag is useful per se, just saying that not every question *must* be about physics sometimes.

Comment: Astrophysics is certainly physics, but the best way to [observe a lunar eclipse](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26255/best-observing-techniques-for-a-total-lunar-eclipse) is astronomy without being at all physics.

Comment: Not that I really care about the tag or difference, I don't have a dog in this fight :)

Comment: @Manishearth [have a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181772/enable-the-intrinsic-sitename-tag-blacklist-on-older-sites) [back](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=13182535#13182535) ;).

Comment: Related http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4768/2451.

Comment: **<comments removed>** Please don't hold tangential discussions here, use [chat].

Answer (score 7):

There is indeed some room for debate on whether all questions on this site must absolutely be about physics, or whether some non-physics astronomy questions are a good fit here. But this debate is irrelevant: questions on this site do *not* have to specify that they're about physics. The tag conveys no information.

Further, it leaves the option for new users to use *only* that tag, e.g. [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/95068/revisions). Chances are, if no other tag applies, that the question is off-topic here. The existence of the [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) tag makes that less evident.

### Please burninate and blacklist it.

Comment: Gaaaah! The tag still has two posts, [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96296/2-bodies-on-a-pulley) and [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/95068/revisions), but it's gonna take at least some ♦ power to strip it off from those.

Comment: Send that tag into a magnetar...

Answer (score 4):

[physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) is now an [intrinsic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181772/enable-the-intrinsic-sitename-tag-blacklist-on-older-sites) tag.