# Why is the 'physics' tag not allowed?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags

Why is the 'physics' tag not allowed?

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: The 'physics' tag is not allowed.
>   Creating the new tag 'physics' requires at least 1000 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead. New tags cannot be created from the mobile site. The tag 'physics' is new.

Comment: Related answer: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5451/59991

Comment: @Qmechanic: [Can you make it grammatical as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us)?

Answer (score 12):

1. Your first obstacle is that you need 1000 reputation points to create a new tag. If you think a tag is missing and don't have 1000 reputation points, you can suggest it in [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/175/2451) meta post.
2. If you have 1000 reputation points, there might be another obstacle: Certain words are blacklisted, e.g. [physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5446/2451).
3. Returning to OP's specific question, a 'physics' tag would be pointless, because then all questions should presumably be tagged with it. The point of tagging is that the tag word should give non-trivial information about the question. A 'physics' tag would not tell us something we didn't know already: That it's about physics!

Comment: More importantly, if the only tag that you can find for your post is 'physics', then there's a better-than-even chance that your question is off-topic here.

Comment: Yeah, that's the other side of the coin.